# How to display wait dialog till a non ui thread is working in a WPF application following MVVM design pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application that follows MVVM design pattern. For threading I intend to use Backgroundworker. From viewmodels,I need to initiate threads to perform time taking opeartions.Please suggest me how to display an wait dialog until the thread is performing. If possible please provide a sample code. 
Regards,
Anirban

Comment: it could be a dialog, but you can just disable all controls or hide them.

Comment: @Anirban Paul - You've asked a lot of questions here on Stack overflow, you don't seem to have accepted any answers yet. That is likely to affect the quality of answers people give you in future...

Answer (score 4):

You could add a property to the ViewModel that indicates that the backgroundworker (or other asynchronous action) is busy.

A View can bind bind to this property to show a progressbar or other busy indicator.

Just make sure you set and reset the property correctly.

**EDIT**

See this question/answer for making a modal dialog in WPF: [How do make modal dialog in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499294/how-do-make-modal-dialog-in-wpf)

As an alternative you could use this setup (pseudo code):

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="regularContent">
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Progressbar Value="{Binding Path=Progress}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ShowPopup()
{
    RegularContent.IsEnabled = false;
    Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void ClosePopup()
{
    RegularContent.IsEnabled = true;
    Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Make sure you disable the regular content to prevent the user from tabbing to it.

You can use the same structure to blockout a part of the View instead of blocking it entirely as I have done.

The Progress property on the ViewModel that the ProgressBar is bound to should be modified on the UI thread. If you are using a backgroundworker that will be done automatically because the ReportProgress event is raised on the UI thread.

If you use a different way of creating a worker thread make sure you use the dispatcher to update the Progress property.

Comment: I need to display a modal wait dialog.If possible please provide sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I used it in Windows Phone :

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
private PerformanceProgressBar loader = new PerformanceProgressBar();
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   bar.IsIndeterminate = true;
   Bar.Enabled = true;
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                       RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   bar.Enabled = false;
}

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

If you want to define a MVVM structure : 
 [PerformanceProgressBar "Invalid cross-thread access" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937525/performanceprogressbar-invalid-cross-thread-access-exception)

Of course an similar user control also exists in WPF : http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Extended%20WPF%20Toolkit%20Controls

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use wpf busyindicator (http://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/).

You can bind it to some thread_is_busy_flag_property in your model model (I prefer it in some singletone accessible through application-wide resource via locator pattern - it's easy to share across xaml and model view/code behind).

Just don't forget about thread safety when setting this flag (or you can use [AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28VS.80%29.aspx) to catch background operation ends). And I suggest to use TPL and tasks (more robust way) instead of BackgroundWorker/QueueUserWorkItem.